# Nginx error: (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream on /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am facing this error while I reading the log using this `sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log`;

My website is loading but everything is black and when I am looking at console log I see this `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

The full error from previews log looks like this

`2019/09/30 16:24:09 [crit] 9103#9103: *81 mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/5" failed (2: No such file or directory) while reading upstream, client: MY_IP, server: dev.example.com, request: "GET /bundle.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/bundle.js", host: "dev.example.com", referrer: "https://dev.example.com/"`

I have tried to give permissions to cache folder but still not working

Answer (score 4):

It says it's failing while trying to create the folder "/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/5".

Check the user nginx is working with and `chown -R user:user /var/cache/nginx` .

And also `chmod -R +x /var/cache/nginx` just to be sure there are enough permissions on the folder.

:)

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have a more creative nginx config, if you change your nginx user after you started your server, nginx will create the proxy folders and files with the default users permissions: `www-data`

In my case, I had changed my `nginx.conf`:

```
user www; # <--- I used www, not www-data
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
```

Upon restart, I got a bunch of errors from the reverse proxy that referenced probably cached files that were cached when the user was `www-data`

Similar to those before me:

```
2023/12/18 18:10:18 [crit] 4104599#4104599: *1752 open() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/6/19/0000000196" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 17x.7x.5x.1xx, server: grafana.example.cxm, request: "GET /public/build/147.73fef960675c84aa9a84.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:13000/public/build/147.73fef960675c84aa9a84.js", host: "grafana.example.cxm"
```

Your version of nginx might place proxies in `/var/lib/nginx/*` and not `/var/cache/nginx/*`

`ls -l /var/lib/nginx/proxy/` should reveal the `user:group`

```
drwx------ 25 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 12 17:25 0
drwx------ 26 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 12 17:25 1
drwx------ 26 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 12 17:25 2
drwx------ 25 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  7 22:36 3
...
```

`ps aux | grep "nginx: worker process"` should reveal the nginx user

```
root       12608  0.0  0.0   6612  2260 pts/2    R+   18:24   0:00 grep nginx: worker process
www      4104599  0.0  0.0  56292  6596 ?        S    10:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
www      4104600  0.0  0.0  56292  6660 ?        S    10:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
www      4104601  0.0  0.0  56292  5700 ?        S    10:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
....
```

As stated above: `sudo chown -R www:www /var/lib/nginx/proxy/*` and your problem will be solved.

Note that the file you need to `chown` will depend on where your version of nginx stores the proxy files and folders (or where you may have configged it to).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was using an api in ASP.NET CORE 6.0 and I was receiving the 502 error, however, when executing the commands below
worked successfully

On Linux, run the command below to check the log

```
# sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied
```

If you are using NGINX, check if you repeatedly encounter denial
avc: denied { name_connect } for pid=XXXXXX comm="nginx" dest=5000

If yes, run the commands below

```
# sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | audit2allow -M mynginx

# sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp
```

Try accessing again.